# How to configure to hide Google Apps Marketplace v2 application on App Launcher?

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I want to use a Google Apps Marketplace application to the user without to be displayed on the App Launcher or to be asked for approval.

Google Apps Marketplace v1 app is not shown on App Launcher when navLink is not set on Application Manifest.

However, v2 configuration is required Universal Navigation Extension or Drive Extension. The application link is shown on App Launcher when The Universal Navigation Extension is set.
[image: displayed Marketplace v2 application on App Launcher]

When a Google Apps organization is set to unable the application, The user who access with "OpenID Connect" is asked for approval.
When Drive Extension is set, to meet the requirements almost, but I don't want to do it as much as possible because it is not in the correct usage.

Please tell me if there is a good way that  is how to set up Google Apps or Google Apps Marketplace.

Thanks.

Comment: For context, why would you want you app to not appear in the launcher?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a solution to the same problem and I've found that using the Drive Extension seems to be the only way forward.

My findings so far are that while it is far from optimal, it does seem to achieve the goal of installing the app without adding it to the Universal Navigation. On the downside though, the app then appears in Google Drive. If you don't configure any MIME types for the application to open, it is relatively hidden, but you can still find the app if you try to configure what apps are available in Google Drive. (see screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vybx5phz6nc62gs/hidden_app.png?dl=0).

I didn't hear it directly, but a colleague has a contact at Google who said that customizing which apps are shown as part of Universal Navigation is an often requested feature that they don't have a timeline for implementing. This rumor is more to substantiate that there is no other way than to offer a glimmer of hope.